# TextMate Capitalize for Snippets

Tags: java, textmate

I've been trying to create a new TextMate snippet that allows me to create the Getters / Setters for Java.

Currently this is all I can come up with:

```
public void set${1:Var}(String $1){
    this.$1 = $1;
}

public String get$1(){
    return $1;
}
```

However, my desired snippet should take the currently selected text, eg. `name` and produce the following output:

```
public String getName(){
     return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name){
     this.name = name;
}
```

To summarize, I need to be able to:

- Get the user's selected text
- Capitalize the first character of the selected text

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex replace within placeholders.

```
public void set${1/./\u$0/}(String $1){
    this.$1 = $1;
}
```

The `\u` will cause the next character to be converted to uppercase.

(See: http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets#transformations)